# Python List syntax and understanding with dynamic programming

Tags: python, list, dynamic

```py
class Solution(object):
 
    def LCS(self, text1,text2 ):
        for i in range(len(text1)-1,-1,-1):
            for j in range(len(text2)-1,-1,-1):
                if text1[i]==text2[j]:
                    dp[i][j]=1+dp[i+1][j+1]
                else:
                    dp[i][j]=max(dp[i][j+1],dp[i+1][j])
        return dp[0][0]
```

Dynamic programming using the bottom-up approach.
This code is for finding the longest common subsequence between two strings.
Example)input; text1='abcde', text2='ace'; then the output should be 3
I am having a difficult time understanding the code after `if text1[i]==text2[j]:`

I am new to python and so I'm not familiar with `arr[i][j]` etc.
I just need an explanation of the code below the if statement along with an explanation of the python syntax.

Comment: How are you learning about python? Does your source not cover this indexing syntax?

Comment: To begin with, this code does not work (there's no `dp` definition at least). Supposing it is list initialized somewhere else, `array[i]` refers to i-th element of array, counting from zero. Same with a string, `'abc'[1]` is `'b'`.

Comment: Python thinks about arrays a little differently than other languages.  `dp` in this case presumably refers to a list object.  `dp[i]` selects the i-th element of that list.  Here, we assume that element is also a list, and `...[j]` selects the j-th element of THAT list.

Comment: I was having a brain fart. Super easy question. Yes, I forgot to add the initialization of dp. Essentially all dp[i][j] is the location on the 2D grid. Such that i is column and j is row. The if statement checks if they match, if they match then look diagonally and do  1 plus diag val. If they don't then look to position [i][j+1] and [i+1][j] which down and the other is to the right and take max and store that val at dp[i][j]

Answer (score 0):

- `dp[p]` *selects* the item at position `p`
- If that item is subscriptable, like a list, then `item[q]` *selects* the object at position `q`.
- `dp[p][q]` *selects* the object at position `q` from the object at position `p` in `dp`